# Jest test fails : TypeError: window.matchMedia is not a function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

This is my first front-end testing experience. In this project, I'm using Jest snapshot testing and got an error `TypeError: window.matchMedia is not a function` inside my component.

I go through Jest documentation, I found the "Manual mocks" section, but I have not any idea about how to do that yet.

Answer (score 291, accepted):

The Jest documentation now has an "official" workaround:

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
  writable: true,
  value: jest.fn().mockImplementation(query => ({
    matches: false,
    media: query,
    onchange: null,
    addListener: jest.fn(), // Deprecated
    removeListener: jest.fn(), // Deprecated
    addEventListener: jest.fn(),
    removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
    dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
  })),
});
```

[Mocking methods which are not implemented in JSDOM](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-methods-which-are-not-implemented-in-jsdom)

Comment: This is the right answer.  Note here that in your test you MUST import the mock BEFORE you import the file you are testing.  

eg 
```
// import '../mockFile'
// import '../fileToTest'
```

Comment: Note that `addListener` and `removeListener` are deprecated, `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` should be used instead. The full mock object can be [found in the Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-methods-which-are-not-implemented-in-jsdom)

Comment: How can the value be changed when mocking like this?

Comment: @evolutionxbox see the answer I just posted, it might help you! (if you're still scratching your head since Feb 28!)

Comment: Where is that snippet supposed to go to solve the problem globally in a project?

Comment: @bluenote10 see the last code block in the docs linked in my answer

Comment: The tests kept failing for me, until I used the solution offered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64813447/cannot-read-property-addlistener-of-undefined-react-testing-library

Comment: Keeps failing for me when testing web with jest and enzyme :(

Comment: I have an expo + next.js set up and keeps failing for web just to add some more context.

Comment: NOTE: The only way this worked for me was to have the code in a separate file (NOT exported, just copy-paste as in the example) and do an import of the file. This example helped me: https://github.com/rickywid/projectx/blob/9c9bafc38988d0cae9946f00a057592d7a0d244e/src/tests/matchmedia.mock.ts

Comment: github link to this bug fix issue: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/21096

Comment: @bluenote10 I would copy past in a [jest-global-mocks.ts](https://thymikee.github.io/jest-preset-angular/docs/9.x/getting-started/installation/#global-mocks) file.

Comment: hm, doesn't seem to work on `window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").addEventListener("change" ...`

Comment: [GitHub solution to "Cannot read property ‘matches’"](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10126#issuecomment-735272763) It is a tweaked version of this answer where you directly redefine the window.matchMedia function.

Answer (score 77):

I've been using this technique to solve a bunch of mocking problems.

```js
describe('Test', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
      writable: true,
      value: jest.fn().mockImplementation((query) => ({
        matches: false,
        media: query,
        onchange: null,
        addListener: jest.fn(), // Deprecated
        removeListener: jest.fn(), // Deprecated
        addEventListener: jest.fn(),
        removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
        dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
      })),
    });
  });
});
```

Or, if you want to mock it all the time, you could put inside your `mocks` file called from your `package.json`:
`"setupFilesAfterEnv": "<rootDir>/src/tests/mocks.js",`.

Reference: [setupTestFrameworkScriptFile](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#setupfilesafterenv-array)

Comment: Where do you add this code? If I add it to the top of my testing file, then it still can’t find matchMedia.

Comment: @HolgerEdwardWardlowSindbæk I edited my answer for more clarity!

Comment: I got a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'matches' of undefined` exception

Comment: Adding following properties addListener: () and removeListener: () helps with avoiding additional fails with missing functions.

Comment: Why `setupFilesAfterEnv` and not `setupFiles`?

Answer (score 49):

I put a *matchMedia* stub in my Jest test file (above the tests), which allows the tests to pass:

```
window.matchMedia = window.matchMedia || function() {
    return {
        matches: false,
        addListener: function() {},
        removeListener: function() {}
    };
};
```

Comment: and with in the test file, inside of 'describe' using jest, I write:
`global.window.matchMedia = jest.fn(() => { return { matches: false, addListener: jest.fn(), removeListener: jest.fn() } })`

Comment: How do you import the stub file?

Comment: This works for one unit test, if you have multiple components having this same issue, you need to put this snippet into each test individually. Typically we want to avoid rewriting the same code, but if that's something that works for you, this is a great quick solution.

Comment: Isn't is `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`?

Answer (score 29):

### JESTS [OFFICIAL WORKAROUND](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-methods-which-are-not-implemented-in-jsdom)

is to create a mock file, called `matchMedia.js` and add the following code:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
    writable: true,
    value: jest.fn().mockImplementation((query) => ({
        matches: false,
        media: query,
        onchange: null,
        addListener: jest.fn(), // Deprecated
        removeListener: jest.fn(), // Deprecated
        addEventListener: jest.fn(),
        removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
        dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
    })),
});
```

Then, inside your test file, import your mock `import './matchMedia';`
and as long as you import it in every use case, it should solve your problem.

### [ALTERNATIVE OPTION](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array)

I kept running into this issue and found myself just making too many imports, thought I would offer an alternative solution.

which is to create a setup/`before.js` file, with the following contents:

```
import 'regenerator-runtime';

/** Add any global mocks needed for the test suite here */

Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
    writable: true,
    value: jest.fn().mockImplementation((query) => ({
        matches: false,
        media: query,
        onchange: null,
        addListener: jest.fn(), // Deprecated
        removeListener: jest.fn(), // Deprecated
        addEventListener: jest.fn(),
        removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
        dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
    })),
});
```

And then inside your jest.config file, add the following:

`setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/`**ROUTE TO YOUR BEFORE.JS FILE**`'],`

Comment: This is the way.

Answer (score 17):

Jest uses [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) to create a browser environment. JSDom doesn't however support `window.matchMedia` so you will have to create it yourself.

Jest's [manual mocks](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/manual-mocks.html) work with module boundaries, i.e. require / import statements so they wouldn't be appropriate to mock `window.matchMedia` as is because it's a global.

You therefore have two options:

1. Define your own local matchMedia module which exports window.matchMedia. -- This would allow you to then define a manual mock to use in your test.
2. Define a [setup file](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#setupfiles-array) which adds a mock for matchMedia to the global window.

With either of these options you could use a [matchMedia polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/match-media) as a mock which would at least allow your tests to run or if you needed to simulate different states you might want to write your own with private methods allowing you to configure it's behaviour similar to the Jest [`fs` manual mock](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/manual-mocks.html)

Answer (score 16):

Add following lines to your `setupTest.js` file,

```
global.matchMedia = global.matchMedia || function() {
    return {
        matches : false,
        addListener : function() {},
        removeListener: function() {}
    }
}
```

This would add match media query for your all test cases.

Comment: This was really useful for me, as all the other fixes extended the `window` object. If you're using Next.js and detecting server-side execution with `typeof window === 'undefined'` then those tests would in turn break.

Comment: You save my day

Comment: this is a fix for "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'matches') at updateMatch" in React 18.

Answer (score 13):

You can mock the API:

```
describe("Test", () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(window, "matchMedia", {
      value: jest.fn(() => {
        return {
          matches: true,
          addListener: jest.fn(),
          removeListener: jest.fn()
        };
      })
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I particularly enjoy the simplicity and clarity of your approach, thanks for posting!

Comment: It works well for me even without this line
```matches: true,```

Answer (score 12):

I have just encountered this issue and had to mock these in jestGlobalMocks.ts:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
  value: () => {
    return {
      matches: false,
      addListener: () => {},
      removeListener: () => {}
    };
  }
});

Object.defineProperty(window, 'getComputedStyle', {
  value: () => {
    return {
      getPropertyValue: () => {}
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: Where do I add this?  I tried adding to a setupFile but it doesnt work

Comment: For me, ultimately, it's the file referred by "setupFile"

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `jest-matchmedia-mock` package for testing any media queries (like device screen change, color-scheme change, etc.)

Comment: most helpful answer so far...works like a charm, thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR answer further down below

In my case, the answer was not enough, as `window.matchMedia` would always return `false` (or `true` if you change it). I had some React hooks and components that needed to listen to **multiple different** queries with possibly different `matches`.

#### What I tried

If you only need to test one query at a time and your tests don't rely on multiple matches, `jest-matchmedia-mock` was useful. However, from what I've understood after trying to use it for 3 hours was that when you call `useMediaQuery`, the previous queries you've made no longer work. In fact, the query you pass into `useMediaQuery` will just match `true` whenever your code calls `window.matchMedia` with that same query, regardless of the actual "window width".

#### Answer

After realizing I couldn't actually test my queries with `jest-matchmedia-mock`, I changed the original answer a bit to be able to mock the behavior of dynamic query `matches`. This solution requires the `css-mediaquery` npm package.

```js
import mediaQuery from "css-mediaquery";

// Mock window.matchMedia's impl.
Object.defineProperty(window, "matchMedia", {
    writable: true,
    value: jest.fn().mockImplementation((query) => {
        const instance = {
            matches: mediaQuery.match(query, {
                width: window.innerWidth,
                height: window.innerHeight,
            }),
            media: query,
            onchange: null,
            addListener: jest.fn(), // Deprecated
            removeListener: jest.fn(), // Deprecated
            addEventListener: jest.fn(),
            removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
            dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
        };

        // Listen to resize events from window.resizeTo and update the instance's match
        window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
            const change = mediaQuery.match(query, {
                width: window.innerWidth,
                height: window.innerHeight,
            });

            if (change != instance.matches) {
                instance.matches = change;
                instance.dispatchEvent("change");
            }
        });

        return instance;
    }),
});

// Mock window.resizeTo's impl.
Object.defineProperty(window, "resizeTo", {
    value: (width: number, height: number) => {
        Object.defineProperty(window, "innerWidth", {
            configurable: true,
            writable: true,
            value: width,
        });
        Object.defineProperty(window, "outerWidth", {
            configurable: true,
            writable: true,
            value: width,
        });
        Object.defineProperty(window, "innerHeight", {
            configurable: true,
            writable: true,
            value: height,
        });
        Object.defineProperty(window, "outerHeight", {
            configurable: true,
            writable: true,
            value: height,
        });
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"));
    },
});
```

It uses `css-mediaquery` with the `window.innerWidth` to determine if the query **ACTUALLY** matches instead of a hard-coded boolean. It also listens to resize events fired by the `window.resizeTo` mocked implementation to update the `matches` value.

You may now use `window.resizeTo` in your tests to change the window's width so your calls to `window.matchMedia` reflect this width. Here's an example, which was made just for this question, so ignore the performance issues it has!

```js
const bp = { xs: 200, sm: 620, md: 980, lg: 1280, xl: 1920 };

// Component.tsx
const Component = () => {
  const isXs = window.matchMedia(`(min-width: ${bp.xs}px)`).matches;
  const isSm = window.matchMedia(`(min-width: ${bp.sm}px)`).matches;
  const isMd = window.matchMedia(`(min-width: ${bp.md}px)`).matches;
  const isLg = window.matchMedia(`(min-width: ${bp.lg}px)`).matches;
  const isXl = window.matchMedia(`(min-width: ${bp.xl}px)`).matches;

  console.log("matches", { isXs, isSm, isMd, isLg, isXl });

  const width =
    (isXl && "1000px") ||
    (isLg && "800px") ||
    (isMd && "600px") ||
    (isSm && "500px") ||
    (isXs && "300px") ||
    "100px";

  return <div style={{ width }} />;
};

// Component.test.tsx
it("should use the md width value", () => {
  window.resizeTo(bp.md, 1000);

  const wrapper = mount(<Component />);
  const div = wrapper.find("div").first();

  // console.log: matches { isXs: true, isSm: true, isMd: true, isLg: false, isXl: false }

  expect(div.prop("style")).toHaveProperty("width", "600px");
});
```

*Note: I have not tested the behavior of this when resizing the window AFTER mounting the component*

Comment: Out of all the solutions this is the only one that actually preserves the functionality of window.matchMedia, which is critical if your app's functionality / layout / etc depends on the media query (as do most reactive apps these days do).

By mocking the matchMedia function in this way, you can dynamically set the window size and test the corresponding behaviour in your test suite.

Many thanks @MaxiJonson !

Comment: Resizing the window after mounting seems to do nothing. To see the updated window value in a rendered component I have to rerender it manually (using `@testing-library/react`).

Answer (score 6):

If you are using typescript, put the lines below in setupTests.ts file. This worked for me:

```
 export default global.matchMedia =
  global.matchMedia ||
  function (query) {
    return {
      matches: false,
      media: query,
      onchange: null,
      addListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
      removeListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
      addEventListener: jest.fn(),
      removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
      dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
    };
  };
```

Answer (score 5):

The official workaround worked for me until I decided to update `react-scripts` from 3.4.1 to 4.0.3 (as I use create-react-app). Then I started getting an error `Cannot read property 'matches' of undefined`.

So here's workaround I found. Install [mq-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mq-polyfill) as dev dependency.

Then code this in `src/setupTests.js`:

```js
import matchMediaPolyfill from 'mq-polyfill'

matchMediaPolyfill(window)

// implementation of window.resizeTo for dispatching event
window.resizeTo = function resizeTo(width, height) {
  Object.assign(this, {
    innerWidth: width,
    innerHeight: height,
    outerWidth: width,
    outerHeight: height
  }).dispatchEvent(new this.Event('resize'))
}
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I tried all the above previous answers without any success.

Adding matchMedia.js to the **mocks** folder, did it for me.

I filled it up with [techguy2000's content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830580/jest-test-fails-typeerror-window-matchmedia-is-not-a-function/49332747#49332747):

```
// __mocks__/matchMedia.js
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
    value: () => ({
        matches: false,
        addListener: () => {},
        removeListener: () => {}
    })
});

Object.defineProperty(window, 'getComputedStyle', {
    value: () => ({
        getPropertyValue: () => {}
    })
});

module.exports = window;
```

And then imported this in `setup.js`:

```
import matchMedia from '../__mocks__/matchMedia';
```

Boom! :)

Answer (score 2):

I developed a library specially designed for that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-match-media

It proposes a complete implementation of `matchMedia` for node.

And it even has a `jest-setup` file you can import in your jest settings to apply this mock to all of your tests (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-match-media#jest):

```js
require('mock-match-media/jest-setup);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also test if the type of `window.matchMedia` is a function before using it

Example :

```js
if (typeof window.matchMedia === 'function') {
    // Do something with window.matchMedia
}
```

And the tests won't fails anymore

Answer (score 2):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53449595/5725619) used to work for me until recently when I updated my packages to the latest versions. I was getting an error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'matches')` as for some reason the jest mock was not working as expected. So replacing the mock with a regular function worked for me:

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
  writable: true,
  value: (query) => ({
    matches: false,
    media: query,
    onchange: null,
    addListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
    removeListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
    addEventListener: jest.fn(),
    removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
    dispatchEvent: jest.fn()
  })
});
```

Comment: I don't get this, your polyfill is exactly the same?

Answer (score 1):

These guys have a pretty slick solution via the Jest setupFiles:

https://github.com/HospitalRun/components/pull/117/commits/210d1b74e4c8c14e1ffd527042e3378bba064ed8

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because I used a library that used `window.matchMedia`

what worked for me was requiring the Component (I use React) under test and the `window.matchMedia` mock inside `jest.isolateModules()`

```
function getMyComponentUnderTest(): typeof ComponentUnderTest {
  let Component: typeof ComponentUnderTest;

  // Must use isolateModules because we need to require a new module everytime so 
  jest.isolateModules(() => {
    // Required so the library (inside Component) won't fail as it uses the window.matchMedia
    // If we import/require it regularly once a new error will happen:
    // `TypeError: Cannot read property 'matches' of undefined`
    require('<your-path-to-the-mock>/__mocks__/window/match-media');
    
    Component = require('./<path-to-component>');
  });

  // @ts-ignore assert the Component (TS screams about using variable before initialization)
  // If for some reason in the future the behavior will change and this assertion will fail
  // We can do a workaround by returning a Promise and the `resolve` callback will be called with the Component in the `isolateModules` function
  // Or we can also put the whole test function inside the `isolateModules` (less preferred)
  expect(Component).toBeDefined();

  // @ts-ignore the Component must be defined as we assert it
  return Component;
}
```

`window.matchMedia` Mock (inside `/__mocks__/window/match-media`):

```js
// Mock to solve: `TypeError: window.matchMedia is not a function`
// From https://stackoverflow.com/a/53449595/5923666

Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
  writable: true,
  value: jest.fn().mockImplementation(query => {
    return ({
      matches: false,
      media: query,
      onchange: null,
      addListener: jest.fn(), // Deprecated
      removeListener: jest.fn(), // Deprecated
      addEventListener: jest.fn(),
      removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
      dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
    });
  }),
});

// Making it a module so TypeScript won't scream about:
// TS1208: 'match-media.ts' cannot be compiled under '--isolatedModules' because it is considered a global script file. Add an import, export, or an empty 'export {}' statement to make it a module.
export {};
```

Answer (score 1):

If the component you are testing includes `window.matchMedia()` or imports another component (ie. a CSS media query hook uses useMedia() ) and you don't aim to test anything related to it, you can bypass calling the method by adding a window check to your component.

In the example code below, useMedia hook will always return false if the code runned by Jest.

There is a post about an argument against mocking module imports., https://dev.to/jackmellis/don-t-mock-modules-4jof

```
import { useLayoutEffect, useState } from 'react';

export function useMedia(query): boolean {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    // ******* WINDOW CHECK START *******
    if (!window || !window.matchMedia) {
      return;
    }
    // ******* WINDOW CHECK END *******

    let mounted = true;
    const mql = window.matchMedia(query);
    const onChange = () => {
      if (!mounted) return;
      setState(!!mql.matches);
    };

    mql.addEventListener('change', onChange);
    setState(mql.matches);

    return () => {
      mounted = false;
      mql.removeEventListener('change', onChange);
    };
  }, [query]);

  return state;
}
```

But if you want to access the object returned from the method, you can mock it in the component itself, instead of testing files. see a sample usage: ([source link](https://github.com/streamich/use-media/blob/b62b992db67f1d18a5e59a2ed42554b29b4b18df/src/useMedia.ts#L26))

```
import {useState, useEffect, useLayoutEffect} from 'react';
import {queryObjectToString, noop} from './utilities';
import {Effect, MediaQueryObject} from './types';

// ************** MOCK START **************
export const mockMediaQueryList: MediaQueryList = {
  media: '',
  matches: false,
  onchange: noop,
  addListener: noop,
  removeListener: noop,
  addEventListener: noop,
  removeEventListener: noop,
  dispatchEvent: (_: Event) => true,
};
// ************** MOCK END **************

const createUseMedia = (effect: Effect) => (
  rawQuery: string | MediaQueryObject,
  defaultState = false,
) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(defaultState);
  const query = queryObjectToString(rawQuery);

  effect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    
    ************** WINDOW CHECK START **************
    const mediaQueryList: MediaQueryList =
      typeof window === 'undefined'
        ? mockMediaQueryList
        : window.matchMedia(query);
    ************** WINDOW CHECK END **************
    const onChange = () => {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }

      setState(Boolean(mediaQueryList.matches));
    };

    mediaQueryList.addListener(onChange);
    setState(mediaQueryList.matches);

    return () => {
      mounted = false;
      mediaQueryList.removeListener(onChange);
    };
  }, [query]);

  return state;
};

export const useMedia = createUseMedia(useEffect);
export const useMediaLayout = createUseMedia(useLayoutEffect);

export default useMedia;
```

Answer (score -3):

```
describe('some test', () => {
window.matchMedia = window.matchMedia || function() {
    return {
        matches: false,
        addListener: function() {},
        removeListener: function() {}
    };
};

test('sdad', ()=> {
})
})
```

Comment: You should probably explain how this answers the question and how this adds something the other answers have not.