# TypeError: j.window.matchMedia is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jestjs

I've implemented Maxime's solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830580/jest-test-fails-typeerror-window-matchmedia-is-not-a-function) about "window.matchMedia" not being found, but when I run my test I get this error: `TypeError: j.window.MatchMedia is not a function`.

I'm not sure what I need to do to get the "j" to resolve, since if I alter the first line from

`Object.defineProperties(window, "matchMedia" {`

to

`Object.defineProperties(j.window, "matchMedia" {`

Jest tells me that it can't resolve "j", which makes sense but doesn't help me understand and fix the error.

Comment: See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830580/jest-test-fails-typeerror-window-matchmedia-is-not-a-function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest test fails : TypeError: window.matchMedia is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830580/jest-test-fails-typeerror-window-matchmedia-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @MattFletcher I think my specific issue was around the 'j' in front of 'window', though I didn't come across the post you liked to when I was looking for existing questions. I'll give this a go, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 5):

> After looking into [the jest solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830580/jest-test-fails-typeerror-window-matchmedia-is-not-a-function) and the documentation briefly about how it's a mock up function... so this variable can be mock up of a function as well.

```
 let mock = () => {}
```

Resolves this TypeError except the j on angular/universal server.ts 10

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
  writable: true,
  value: (query: any) => { return {
  matches: false,
  media: query,
  onchange: null,
  addListener: mock, // deprecated         
  removeListener: mock, // deprecated
  addEventListener: mock,
  removeEventListener: mock,
  dispatchEvent: mock,
 }}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `@angular-builders/jest` you can add this to your angular.json:

```
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-builders/jest:run",
      "options": {
        "globalMocks": [
          "matchMedia"
        ]
      }
    },
```

This builder allows you to run your jest tests with ng test as well. Documentation on how to install this can be found here: https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/jest#builder-options