# Strange Bug Mocking Window Match Media with React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, mocking

I'm testing an app.js file and am mocking `window.matchmedia` for this. I've got it to work but am confused why my code works but the one in the jest documentation doesn't as described [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-methods-which-are-not-implemented-in-jsdom) and noted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830580/jest-test-fails-typeerror-window-matchmedia-is-not-a-function) SO question.

This is my `app.test.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./app.js";


window.matchMedia = (query) => ({
    matches: false,
    media: query,
    onchange: null,
    addEventListener: jest.fn(),
    removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
    dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
  })

test("renders App component", () => {
  render(<App />);
  expect(screen.getAllByText("Blog")).toHaveLength(2);
});
```

And here is my `app.js`:

```
import GlobalStyles from "../GlobalStyles/globalStyles.js";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import LandingPage from "../Landing/landing.js";
import About from "../About/about.js";
import Contact from "../Contact/contact.js";
import Blog from "../Blog/blog.js";
import Work from "../Work/work.js";
import DarkModeSwitch from "../DarkModeSwitch/darkModeSwitch.js";
import NotFound from "../NotFound/404.js";
import { lightTheme, darkTheme } from "../Theme/theme.js";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

/**
 * Main App function. Uses client side routing with React Router and some global styles and theming.
 * I've included a dark mode switch here rather than refactoring into a hook since it just feels simpler.
 */
function App() {

  // Find user local preferences for dark/light theme
  const prefersDark = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches;
  const initialTheme = prefersDark ? darkTheme : lightTheme;
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(initialTheme);
  const [switcher, setSwitcher] = useState(true);

  /**
   * Handles clicks on the dark mode switch; these themes are then passed into ThemeProvider which injects styles
   * into the whole app.
   */
  function clickHandler() {
    setSwitcher(switcher ? false : true);
    setTheme(switcher ? lightTheme : darkTheme);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <GlobalStyles />
        <DarkModeSwitch onClick={clickHandler} />
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
            <Route exact path="/" element={<LandingPage />}></Route>
            <Route exact path="/about" element={<About />}></Route>
            <Route exact path="/contact" element={<Contact />}></Route>
            <Route exact path="/blog" element={<Blog />}></Route>
            <Route exact path="/work" element={<Work />}></Route>
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

...and this is what jest says you're supposed to do and which doesn't work for me when I put in my `app.test.js` even though I think it should:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
  writable: true,
  value: jest.fn().mockImplementation(query => ({
    matches: false,
    media: query,
    onchange: null,
    addListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
    removeListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
    addEventListener: jest.fn(),
    removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
    dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
  })),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me.

I created a file named **setupTests.js** with this function:

```
export const mockMatchMedia = () => {
  window.matchMedia = query => ({
    matches: false,
    media: query,
    onchange: null,
    addListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
    removeListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
    addEventListener: jest.fn(),
    removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
    dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
  });
};
```

Then, i added this in my test file:

```
beforeAll(() => {
  mockMatchMedia();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
export default global.matchMedia =
  global.matchMedia ||
  function (query) {
    return {
      matches: false,
      media: query,
      onchange: null,
      addListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
      removeListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
      addEventListener: jest.fn(),
      removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
      dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
    };
  };
```

and import file in all tests

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).