# How to test matchMedia with react-testing-library/jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

Code below that I need to test -

```
  const [item, setItem] = useState(() => {
    let initialItem = 'both';

    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1012px)').matches) {
        initialItem = 'signup';
      } else if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1460px)').matches) {
        initialItem = 'info';
      }
    }

    return initialItem;
  });

  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1012px)').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
      if (event.matches) {
        setItem('signup');
      }
    });

    window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1460px)').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
      if (event.matches) {
        setItem('info');
      }
    });

    window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1460px)').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
      if (event.matches) {
        setItem('both');
      }
    });
  }
```

I am struggling to test this. This is what I have at the moment -

```
test('should update layout on window resize', () => {
    window.matchMedia = jest.fn().mockImplementation((query) => ({
      matches: query !== '(max-width: 1011px)',
      media: '',
      onchange: null,
      addEventListener: jest.fn(),
      removeListener: jest.fn(),
    }));

    globalThis.innerWidth = 1500;
    renderTestComponent();
    expect(screen.getByTestId('item')).toHaveTextContent('both');
    

    // Resize the window to small
    globalThis.innerWidth = 1000;
    globalThis.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    expect(screen.getByTestId('item')).toHaveTextContent('box');
```

How can I test that the correct item is shown when the screen changes sizes. Especially with using matchMedia?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64520587/6463558