# Why do I keep on getting "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'matches')" when running a simple test on react testing library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I have tried by best to figure out the issue but everything I tried so far has not been working.

This is what my App.js looks like:

```
import './App.css';
import {ChakraProvider} from '@chakra-ui/react'
import Header from './components/Header'
import Hero from './components/Hero'
import Highlights from './components/Highlights.js'
import About from './components/About.js'
import Footer from './components/Footer.js'
import Reserve from './components/Reserve.js'
import '@fontsource/karla'
import '@fontsource/markazi-text'
import theme from './theme'
import { Routes, Route,} from "react-router-dom";

function Homepage(){
  return(
    <>
      <Hero/>
      <Highlights/>
      <About/>
      <Footer/>
    </>
  )
}
function App() {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
      <Header/>
      <main>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Homepage/>}/>
          <Route path='/Reservations' element={<Reserve/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </main>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my App.test.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import Reserve from './components/Reserve';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

test('render reservations page header', () => {
  render(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <Reserve />
    </MemoryRouter>
  )
expect(screen.getByText('Reservations')).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

This is a picture of the error messsage:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zPgR.png)

I tried using the history library, but that did not work. As well as the wrapper option and tried using BrowserRouter and nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the error is related to the `useMediaQuery` hook. I'm using `useMediaQuery` from '@material-ui/core' library, but I hope that the fix is compatible with your library.

In React 18.2 project, addition of the following lines to `setupTest.js` file helped me to resolve the issue.

```js
global.matchMedia = global.matchMedia || function() {
    return {
        matches: false,
        addListener: function() {},
        removeListener: function() {}
    }
}
```

<sup>src: [Jest test fails: TypeError: window.matchMedia is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68539103/1429387)</sup>

The [official workaround](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-methods-which-are-not-implemented-in-jsdom) that looks like `Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', { ... })` doesn't work in React 18. Delete it, if you used it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be wrapping your `Routes` with `BrowserRouter` in your App. Your test should also have this import:

`import "@testing-library/jest-dom";`

Using your code modified to test in this [example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-testing-library-example-xwo6zq) I'm not having any issues.

**App.js**

```
import Reserve from "./Reserve.js";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Reserve />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Reserve.js**

```
function Reserve() {
  return <span>Reservations</span>;
}

export default Reserve;
```

**App.test.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import Reserve from "./Reserve";

test("render reservations page header", () => {
  render(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <Reserve />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
  expect(screen.getByText("Reservations")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Also make sure you're not using an outdated version of testing library with a new version of react.

Comment: I followed your exact steps but still getting the same type error as before, also I am using react v18.2.0 and react testing library v13.4. 
Side note: I have run the same test on other react projects, the test runs and passes as expected, the only difference is I don't have routes on any of them.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem is actually in the Reserve.js file, it is using useMediaQuery from chakra-ui

This is a representation of the Reserve.js file:

```
import React from 'react'
import {useMediaQuery} from '@chakra-ui/react'

export default function Reserve() {
    const [isLargerThan800] = useMediaQuery('(min-width: 800px)')

    if (isLargerThan800 === true){
        render (<p>desktop</p>)
    }
    else {
        render (<p>mobile</p>)
    }
}
```

The optimum solution was to mock this hook and pass it a value in the test file, however I tried several mocking methods and each produced a different type of error.

I was able to bypass the problem by giving the hook a constant value in the Reserve.js file during tests

```
//const [isLargerThan800] = useMediaQuery('(min-width: 800px)')
let isLargerThan800 = true
```

If any onlooker knows how to correctly mock this hook your help will be much appreciated!